# Guardar obj con php en mysql

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo este onClick en js

```
$("#TblAsigRol > tbody").on('click', '.c_BtnGurdarRol', function(event) 
{
     var nombre= event.target.id;
     var toRemove = 'btnguardar';
     var id= nombre.replace(toRemove,'');

     //se toma la c�dula
     var idempleado = 'documen_ident' + '' +  id;
     var doc= $("#" + idempleado).val();

     //Se toma el valor del rol
     var idrol = 'rol' + '' +  id;
     var rolemp= $("#" + idrol).val();
     console.log(cdc2);
     //alert(doc + " " +  rolemp);
    procesarDatos("ModificarRol", {idoc:doc, rol:rolemp, obj:cdc2 });

});
```

el problema que tengo es que el objeto cdc2 el cual llega con un valor de 
**0:"CCC0"** .
entonces al pasar los valores en una funcion en php la cual es

```
function ModificarRol($datos)
       {    

              $FechaActual= fechaActual();

              $sql = 'UPDATE `empleados` SET idrol=\''. $datos['rol']. '\' , UsuarioModificion=\''. $_SESSION['NombreUsario']. '\' , FechaModificacion=\''. $FechaActual. '\' WHERE docum_ident = \''.$datos['idoc'] . '\';';
              $result = execute_query($sql);


              foreach ($datos['obj']  as $row ) {

                  $sql = 'INSERT INTO `detalle_usuarioxcc` (`docum_ident`, `CentroCosto`) VALUES ("'.$datos['idoc'].'", "'.$row['obj'].'")';
                  $result = execute_query($sql);
              }

              echo json_encode($result);
        }
```

Al momento de insertar en obj en mysql solo me esta insertando el primer carácter es decir en la tabla queda  CentroCosto = C

Comment: Había sido útil ver un `var_dump($datos);` para saber exactamente lo que hay en tu objeto datos. No obstante, aquí: `foreach ($datos['obj']  as $row ) {` se supone que ya estás dentro de la clave `obj`, por lo tanto el `foreach` te leerá solamente los valores con esa clave que estén dentro de `$datos`, y quizá por eso cuando haces `$row['obj']` te trae solamente la primera letra de `$row`. Prueba a poner solamente `$row` en vez de `$row['obj']`...

Comment: ... Aunque me parece extraño tu código, hay algo que no me cuadra, pues veo que por un lado en el `foreach` pides `$datos['obj'] ` y luego usas también...`$datos['idoc']` dentro de ese mismo bucle ¿Acaso `idoc` es una llave que está dentro de la llave `obj` del objeto `$datos`?. Sería bueno ver cómo está constituido en sí el objeto `$datos` para salir de las dudas.

Comment: `$datos['idoc']` es por que necesito insertarla con el documento, pero al insertar  `$row['obj']` lo toma como si fuera un vector entonces me instar la letra C que esta en la posición 0

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar por favor lo que arroja `var_dump($datos);` ?

Comment: Me sirvió poniendo `$row`, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.